# Yocto kernel is bigger than 1GB

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-kirkstone

I need my  poky to run all in ram(64GB).

I tried to bundle the kernel with the rootFS, I was expecting a distro that would load to RAM on boot, using:

```
INITRAMFS_IMAGE_BUNDLE="1"
```

but the kernel becomes to big (almost 6GB) and yocto stops with error:

> "kernel image bigger than KERNEL_IMAGE_SIZE"

any ideas?

Comment: What image were you bundling?

Comment: It is a very specific image for intel xion with nvidia drivers and more